# When adding new module to angular project then nothing is showing up in browser?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

When I add a new module called "*MatGridListModule*" to the imports section, nothing is displayed in the browser. There should be something at least. I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xc7Nd.png)
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ODZ9.png)
[Browser blank page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvvNR.png)

https://material.angular.io/components/grid-list/api

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { TestComponentComponent } from './test-component/test-component.component';
import {MatGridListModule} from '@angular/material/grid-list';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TestComponentComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MatGridListModule
  ],
  exports: [
    MatGridListModule,
],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Read this: [ask]

Comment: you should be using command line to add a component. `ng g c mat-grid-list-module`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Jay Swaminarayan!
Make Sure you have added @angular/material

https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

And then restart the project to see if that works